# refresh eclipse cdt system includes

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I'm using ecipse cdt developing c++ program. A problem is I moved all my workspace and eclipse package from turbolinux to centos linux. Then it cause a problem, that is system includes are different, but eclipse didn't refresh the include paths. And all the std container classes can not be solved.

Anyone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 12):

I was recently bitten by this one myself (actually came to this site in search of an answer ;-) so I'll share what I found:

(these steps reflect Eclipse Indigo SR1)

First, double-check that Eclipse still reflects the old include paths:

- project -> properties -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> GNU C++

Next, clear the old paths:

- project -> properties -> C/C++ Build -> Discovery Options -> GCC C++ Compiler
- click the button for "Clear discovered entries now"

Rebuild your project, such that Eclipse picks up on the new include paths

Confirm that the new include paths are set:

- project -> properties -> C/C++ General -> Paths and Symbols -> GNU C++

Comment: Thanks, seems these steps can not solve the problem on my system. Don't know what's the wrong with eclipse. Currently I have to add include path myself, I exported standard paths into a file and every time i create new project I import that file. However this way sounds a little stupid. :)

Comment: Make sure to select "Managed Build System - per project..." insted of "GCC per file scanner..." in Discovery-Options window. Should some problems persist, run Project>Index>Rebuild.

Answer (score 1):

Checked for Eclipse Luna 4.4.0 with Cdt 8.4.0.201406111759.

You may have a look to your `workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.core/` and check for a file named like `YourProjectName.language.settings.xml`.

Delete this file (better should backup before), then reopen your project (or restart Eclipse) and Cdt should trigger the the GCC Builtin Discovery.

Note that this way may only applyable if your settings are set to project specific Builtin Discovery (not for »Use global provider shared between projects«). → see `Project Properties → C/C++ General → Preprocessor Include Paths, Macros etc. → Providers → CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings`.

For older Eclipse versions (IMHO about until Indigo), the scanner cache files were placed in `workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.make.core/` and named like `YourProjectName.sc`.

Answer (score 1):

In the newest Eclipse CDT Mars.1 Release (4.5.1) you'll have to delete the `${WORKSPACE}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.core/${PROJECTNAME}.randomnumbers.pdom` file, and after opening the project, Eclipse should automatically start to reindex the includes.

Comment: Still works in Eclipse 2022-03 (4.23.0).