# moved my mingw installation - now eclipse cdt can't resolve the includes

Tags: eclipse, mingw, eclipse-cdt

I went to `Project->Properties->C/C++ General->Paths and Symbols` and indeed the paths are the ones of my old mingwin install. My question is : is there an easy way to tell eclipse to reset the toolchain - *for the workspace not per project* ? Of course when I installed the CDT having already mingwin in my PATH I did not configure anything manually and I'd like to avoid it now

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8805675/281545). Go to `Project > properties > C/C++ General > Paths and Symbols > GNU C++` - you will notice the paths point to old installation. Clear them in `Project > properties > C/C++ Build > Discovery Options > GCC C++ Compiler` and press the `Clear` button in the Automated discovery of paths and symbols box by the *Clear discovered entries now* label.

Rebuild your project.

Valid for Eclipse Juno.

If someone could explain how to do this not on a per project basis but for the whole workspace (the clean up of the settings) it would be much appreciated (and accepted). The paths are hardcoded in `${workspace_loc}\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.cdt.make.core\<project_name>.sc` files - the usual total epic mess with eclipse prefs being scattered all over the place - grr. Would the answer to my original question be to search and replace the paths there (and only there ?) ?

**EDIT :** Of note are the items in `Project > Index` menu - maybe a more appropriate way to do the same thing ?

Answer (score 1):

The settings changed in release 8.1 (Eclipse Juno) and can be set globally for all projects. At least that's what they advertised.

In `Window > Preferences > C/C++ > Build > Settings`, select `CDT GCC Built-in Compiler Settings MinGW` then `Clear Entries` and `Reset`. In my version (CDT 8.2, Eclipse Kepler), the project specific settings `Discovery Options` does not exist anymore.

Some links about this:

1. http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/NewIn81#Scanner_Discovery
2. http://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#What_is_a_Scanner_Discovery.3F

In my specific case, it did work but no for everything, and not for the most important the `Path and Symbols` settings. I had to manually edit the `<project_name>.sc` file in the workspace.

Hope this helps someone else.

Matt

Comment: Thanks - will have to verify and possibly accept your answer :)

Comment: Hope it's fully resolved one day. It's going in the right direction I think. You can keep your answer accepted, my answer is more as an addendum for other users :)